# Sharepoint Folder listing takes time to load

Tags: sharepoint

I have around 1000 folders. when i select a document and click on 'move to' ,the folder listing window is loading for a long time and then showing the data. How can we speed up the loading?

Answer (score 0):

the first rule of SharePoint: **you do not create folders**! 
I know, it is too late now, but here it's what you should be doing now to fix this situation and avoid a bigger catastrophe:

1. create views to filter out the drilling down into sub-folders
2. views are your best friend in this scenario, you can improve the time of loading with better tailored views allied with indexes
3. employ metadata, actually this goes hand to hand with tailored views

**Final step:**

Once you have deployed tailored views to address the navigation to your data, you will start removing the folders, from the document library, the way how the users will find their info will be based on views and metadata.

You do not user document libraries the analogue way as use our hard disk by creating folders, we store data inside and provide Views to help users to find their info, the views filter out the unwanted data and present what you want to see, the metadata helps you to categorize, classify, and archive information, when all is combined, SharePoint index the data and presents you with agility, users once instructed to use views will never wait for long loading times!